# Dialogflow - Sentiment analysis - SentimentAnalysisResult obj is null sometimes

Tags: dialogflow-es

I am trying to do sentiment analysis from the c# code. I have enabled the sentiment analysis to true.

```
DetectIntentRequest detectIntentRequest = new DetectIntentRequest(); 
detectIntentRequest.QueryInput = queryInput; 
detectIntentRequest.SessionAsSessionName = _sessionName; 
detectIntentRequest.QueryParams = new QueryParameters(); detectIntentRequest.QueryParams.SentimentAnalysisRequestConfig = new SentimentAnalysisRequestConfig(); detectIntentRequest.QueryParams.SentimentAnalysisRequestConfig.AnalyzeQueryTextSentiment = true;
```

For few sentences, I get the **SentimentAnalysisResult** in present response. But for few sentences the SentimentAnalysisResult is null in response.

For example: When i send following as query string to detectIntent.

Show me possibilities not in Maharashtra - **This gives valid result.**

Show me possibilities in Maharashtra but not in pune - **This gives SentimentAnalysisResult as null**